# need to transform Data from Rows to Column with a Loop Condition with parent child

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, ms-office, formula

[image: I got a file in this format. and in this file, I got the data into a single column only. Which is not the best presentation to understand the data]

I have data from the cell A36 - A17536 in a single column. The best presentation for this data is to make the cell A36 as a parent, and the below 17 cells from A37 - A53 as it's values in the same row. We have the exact set of 18 Values data (into same column) that should me transform into rows, 1st value as parent and the 2nd-18th as it's value in the same row. Now, excel should automatically make the 19th value as a parent as at this time it is the exact same value as A36. Excel should repeat this process until it can obtain data in the same column. This can be a loop to perform the same action again nd again.  [image: Here is the solution I'm looking for]

Comment: If available use `WRAPROWS(A36:A17536,17)`

Comment: This can be done without the WRAP functions if you don’t have O365.  I want to highlight something important in developing an understanding of Excel.  The words “looping through” will tend to form the incorrect intuition about how excel formulas work, and thus taint what approaches we consider.  A procedural language like VBA will “loop through” and and decide where to put each value.  Excel formulas by definition “pull” data into the cell in a way that is defined by the formula.  You will have a single formula, or a grid of formulas, that know how to pull their values from the long list.